# How to print a row of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, std

I am fairly new to C++ programming, and I am getting stuck at how to print values from a specific row.

I mean:

```
std::string musical_things [][][] = {
    {
        {"Scale"}, {"Minor Natural"}, {"1","2","b3","4","5","b6","b7"}
    },
    {
        {"Scale"}, {"Major"}, {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"}
    },

};
```

So, when I try to access just a single full row, I get the memory address.
If I loop it, I get the memory address of each element.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       std::cout << "Output: " << musical_things [i]<< "\n" << std::endl;
```

And I am just trying to get `musical_things [i]`.
For i = 0, output should be: `{"Scale"}, {"Chromatic"}, {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"}`.

Comment: there is no automagic way to print a row of the array. You need to do it yourself by iterating the individual elements

Comment: When I iterate over the 1D I just get memory addresses, not values.

Comment: in the code you posted you iterate the outermost dimension `musical_things[i]` is a 2d array. `musical_things[i][j]` is a 1d array and its elements `musical_things[i][j][k]` are strings that you can print via `std::cout <<`

Comment: however, you shouldn't be using a 3d array here. It makes things unnecessarily compilcated. Rather write a struct that contains the data and use a `std::vector<my_struct>`

Comment: But I just want to print out the whole row, located at `musical_things[i]`, and I get this:``` Output: 0x4133e0

Output: 0x413740

Output: 0x413aa0

Output: 0x413e00

Output: 0x414160

Output: 0x4144c0

Output: 0x414820

Output: 0x414b80

Output: 0x414ee0

Output: 0x415240```

Comment: unfortunately c++ doesnt care about what you want. There is no way to print the row of your matrix other than iterating the individual strings and print them

Comment: But for my purpose it's complicated using a vector, 'cause I will had to overload the cout operator and that it's still far away from the point that I am now.

Comment: "cause I will had to overload the cout operator " no, thats not a disadvantage of `std::vector`. You cannot print a vector as you want just like you cannot print an array as you want. Your immediate problem would be exactly the same with a vector, just the the solution is sooooo much easier

Comment: its a common misunderstanding that using `std::vector` is more compilcated than using c-arrays. This could not be more wrong. Most likely this is caused by wrong teaching. Using a `std::vector` is simpler than using a c-array in almost any possible way

Comment: It seems you are writing C++ more like C. As others have said, C++ has container classes that do everything that arrays do and more (not least because they handle memory allocation and are simple to grow). I realize that a "I wouldn't have done it this way in the first place" response may not solve your immediate problem, but it is true in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your data doesn't fit a 3-D array model: the individual arrays are of different length, which will make the compiler "pad" them with zero-valued characters. This is a great amount of padding, and, what's worse, it's not easily predictable.

For example, the longest string in your data has 13 characters, so all strings will be padded to that size (including e.g. `"1"`). Also, the longest list of strings contains 7 strings, so all lists will be padded to that size. So your array `{"Scale"}` will be padded to an array of 7 strings, with strings which contain 13 zero-values characters.

This is really not what you want. You can ignore it (you really don't care if compiler does unnecessary work) but it will backfire when you try to count your strings - you will have to ignore the empty strings somehow.

Assuming you want to fix this, note that your data is a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) of strings and not a 3-D array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> musical_things =
{
    {
        {"Scale"}, {"Minor Natural"}, {"1","2","b3","4","5","b6","b7"}
    },
    {
        {"Scale"}, {"Major"}, {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"}
    },
};
```

To make code which prints it, I decided to use bottom-up approach, which is easy to explain.

First of all, I made a function which prints a string in the format you want:

```
void print(std::ostream& stream, const std::string& string)
{
    stream << '"' << string << '"';
}
```

---

Then, I made a function which prints an array of strings:

```
void print(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<std::string>& array)
{
    bool first_time = true;
    stream << '{';
    for (const std::string& s: array)
    {
        if (!first_time)
            stream << ",";
        print(stream, s);
        first_time = false;
    }
    stream << '}';
}
```

It iterates over the array, and calls the `print` function for each string. It cannot use `operator<<` because you want each string to be enclosed in quotes.

It uses the `first_time` flag to print the separators properly - there is one separator fewer than the number of strings.

---

Finally, the code which prints an array of arrays:

```
void print(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& array)
{
    bool first_time = true;
    for (const auto& v: array)
    {
        if (!first_time)
            stream << ", ";
        print(stream, v);
        first_time = false;
    }
}
```

It's mostly the same, but it uses a different separator, and the type of the loop-variable is `const auto&`, because I was too lazy to type `const std::vector<std::string>&` (I let the compiler deduce it).

<sub>Oops, I've just typed it! So I actually wasn't lazy :)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload for `ostream`s operator `<<` that does what you want directly. You need to iterate the strings and print them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  std::cout << "Output: ";
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
         std::cout << musical_things[i][j][k];
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I assumed all dimensions are of size 10, which isnt the case in your example. Managing sizes of multidimensional c-arrays is a mess, you should use a `std::vector` instead, or rather define a struct that holds data the belongs together. Chances are high that you actually only need a single dimensional `std::vector<my_struct>`.